Images Not Displaying on Live Server (Shared Hosting)
Images stored in the public/storage directory are not displaying on the live server (shared hosting environment), but they work perfectly on localhost.
Relevant Code
Trainee.php Method
public function getProfilePicture()
{
  if ($this->picture && Storage::disk('public')->exists($this->picture) == 1) {
         return Storage::disk('public')->url($this->picture);
    }

    return asset('/images/blank_profile_picture.png');
}

Blade Template
<img src="{{ $trainee->getProfilePicture() }}">

filesystems.php Configuration
'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
            'serve' => true,
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
],

Commands Executed on Shared Hosting (via SSH)
Below are the commands I ran to set up the symbolic link for the storage directory:
php artisan storage:link
  INFO  The [public/storage] link has been connected to [storage/app/public].
chmod -R 755 storage
chmod -R 755 public/storage

Verifications
After running the commands:

The symbolic link was created successfully:

ls -l public
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 61 Dec 17 10:22 storage -> /home/customer/www/.../storage/app/public

... contains the app path that I'm passing in .env as  APP_URL

The file exists in the storage/app/public/trainee-profile-pictures directory:

ls -l storage/app/public/trainee-profile-pictures/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 26990 Dec 17 07:36 gAgoBddnYT7SH0eiV2u000bqZT5j2TGQjcoedHlj.jpg```

Expected Output
The getProfilePicture() method in the Trainee.php model should return the correct URL of the image, and the <img> tag in the Blade template should display the image.
Debugging Observations
Actual image path:

/storage/app/public/trainee-profile-pictures/gAgoBddnYT7SH0eiV2u000bqZT5j2TGQjcoedHlj.jpg

Values observed during debugging:
$this->picture = trainee-profile-pictures/gAgoBddnYT7SH0eiV2u000bqZT5j2TGQjcoedHlj.jpg
Storage::disk('public')->exists($this->picture) = 1
$trainee->getProfilePicture() = https://.../storage/trainee-profile-pictures/gAgoBddnYT7SH0eiV2u000bqZT5j2TGQjcoedHlj.jpg
storage_path('app/public/'.$this->picture) =
/home/customer/www/.../storage/app/public/trainee-profile-pictures/gAgoBddnYT7SH0eiV2u000bqZT5j2TGQjcoedHlj.jpg

Observations:

The symbolic link appears to be created correctly.
The image exists in the specified directory.
Despite this, the fallback image is being returned by the getProfilePicture() method.

Request
Please guide me on:

Whether there’s an issue with the symbolic link or file permissions.
Any misconfiguration in the filesystems.php or hosting environment.
Steps to ensure the images display properly on the live server.


Which of those conditions fail in if block?

How exactly did you make your debugging observations?
Could you try to add the following at the top of the getProfilePicture method and share the result?
dd($this->picture == true, Storage::disk('public')->exists($this->picture) == 1); 

Also, does the user under which your web server process is executed (typically www-admin) belong to the “user” group?

@Tpojka both conditions inside if are true

@jschpmr I was showing in the frontend end. Just using <p> I know thats not it.
<p>file_path: {{ $trainee->picture }}</p>
<p>exists: {{ Storage::disk('public')->exists($trainee->picture) }}</p>
<p>url: {{ Storage::url($trainee->picture) }}</p>
<p>trainee->getProfilePicture(): {{ $trainee->getProfilePicture() }}</p>
<p>storage_path: {{ storage_path($trainee->picture) }}</p>```

@FaizanKamal Checking these conditions in the frontend is not really the way to go from my point of view. You should really check the conditions used in the if statement in getProfilePicture directly where they are evaluated.
Also, if  both conditions are true, it is impossible for the return statement returning the blank profile picture asset to be reached.

@jschpmr return is always returning https://<live_Server_domain>/storage/trainee-profile-pictures/gAgoBddnYT7SH0eiV2u000bqZT5j2TGQjcoedHlj.jpg

What problem remains then? (In your Post you wrote 'Obersvations: Despite this, the fallback image is being returned by the getProfilePicture() method.'

https://<live_Server_domain>/storage/trainee-profile-pictures/gAgoBddnYT7SH0eiV2u000bqZT5j2TGQjcoedHlj.jpg is not showing on frontend.  Purposing of sharing te image link is to see if the link is being returned in rightly manner. Because it is not showing up in the frontend when pass it to img
Image's actual path is app/public/trainee-profile-pictures/gAgoBddnYT7SH0eiV2u000bqZT5j2TGQjcoedHlj.jpg I verified it. But still no image is being shown on frontend. On local host everything is working fine but not on live server
